# Exactly what is the difference between a "closure" and a "block"?

Tags: programming-languages, computer-science, theory, language-theory

I've found that lots of people use the words *closure* and *block* interchangeably. Most of these people can't explain what they're talking about.

Some Java programmers (even ones from really expensive consultancies) talk about anonymous inner classes as "blocks" and "closures" - but I know this isn't true. (You can't pass mutable variables in from the scope of the method in which they're defined...)

I'm looking for:

- a precise, computer science **definition of a block**
- a precise, computer science **definition of a closure**
- and **clarification on the difference** between the two.

I'd really like to see links, articles or book **references on these please**.

Comment: I'm not sure they have precise definitions, for instance the closures Apple added to gcc are called "blocks"

Comment: If you're talking about the []'s - they got into Objective-C from Smalltalk where they are compiled into an instance of the confusingly named `BlockClosure`.

Comment: He's not talking about Objective-C, he's talking about Apple's extensions to C. In OSX 10.6 Snow Leopard, Appel introduced a new concurrency library called Grand Central Dispatch. It's a task-based library somewhat similar to Microsoft's Task Parallel Library. The basic idea of GCD is that you hand a block of code to the library and the library then decides when and on which core to execute. Normally, you would do that with function pointers, but Apple deemed that too ugly and they extended C with essentially lambda expressions, which they call blocks.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

While a **block** is just a piece of code that can be composed by statements and declarations but nothing else, a **closure** is a real first-class object, a real variable that has a block as its value.

The main difference is that a block simply groups instructions together (for example the body of a *while* statement), while a closure is a variable that contains some code that can be executed.

If you have a closure usually you can pass it as a parameter to functions, currify and decurrify it, and mainly call it!

```
Closure c = { println 'Hello!' }
/* now you have an object that contains code */
c.call()
```

Of course closures are more powerful, they are variables and can be used to define custom behaviour of objects (while usually you had to use **interfaces** or other OOP approaches in programming).

You can think of a **closure** as a function that contains what that function does inside itself.

Blocks are useful because they allow scoping of variables. Usually when you define a variable inside a scope you can override the outer definitions without any problems and new definitions will exist just during the execution of block.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
     int t = i*2;
     printf("%d\r\n", t);
}
```

`t` is defined inside the block (the body of the `for` statement) and will last just inside that block.

Comment: The for-loop example doesn't fly generically, as "closure" is verbiage used with Javascript more than with other languages and for loop blocks do not encapsulate their variables at all except *only* with function declarations. I suspect your example is Java? Please specify.

Comment: "While a block is just a piece of code..." Tell that to a demented Ruby programmer.

Comment: @Jack can you explain a real first-class object, as if we consider a block it can be 1. passed as an argument, 2. it can be returned from a function and 3. assigned to a variable.

Comment: @Shardul: I don't know your programming background but some programming languages call 'block' what is instead a lambda or closure. Traditionally a block is just an enclosement for multiple statements, as the body of an if, so you can't do anything that you stated with it.

Comment: In order to be a *closure*, the object has to capture surrounding lexical scope. Otherwise it's just an anonymous function.

Answer (score 19):

A block is something syntactical - A logical unit of statements (more related to *scope* than to *closure*).

```
if (Condition) {
    // Block here 
} 
else {
    // Another block
}
```

A closure is related to anoymous functions or classes - An anonymous (function) object, a piece of code that is bound to an environment (with its variables).

```
def foo() {
   var x = 0
   return () => { x += 1; return x }
}
```

Here `foo` returns a closure! The local variable `x` persists through the closure even after `foo` terminated and can be incremented through calls of the returned anonymous function.

```
val counter = foo()
print counter() // Returns 2
print counter() // Return 3
```

Note that's just Ruby in which block and closure are treated similarly since what Ruby calls block *is a* closure:

```
(1..10).each do |x|
    p x
end
```

There `each`-method is passed a closure function (taking a parameter x) which is called a *block* in Ruby.

Comment: ... then there's the confusion with Smalltalk. What Ruby programmers call a block, Smalltalk calls a `BlockClosure`!

Comment: Actually, in your Ruby example, the block is *not* a closure, because it doesn't close over anything. More interesting would be `a = 7; (1..10).each do |x| p a << x end` or something like that.

Answer (score 8):

There's a lot of confusion around here because there are terms with multiple definitions, and multiple distinct things that get conflated simply because they're usually found together.

First, we have "block". That's just a lexical chunk of code that makes a unit - the body of a loop, for instance.  If the language actually has block scope, then variables can be defined that only exist within that chunk of code.

Second, we have callable code as a value type. In functional languages, these are function values - sometimes called "funs", "anonymous functions" (because the function is found in the value, not the name its assigned to; you don't need a name to call them), or "lambdas" (from the operator used to create them in Church's Lambda Calculus).  They may be called "closures", but they aren't automatically true closures; in order to qualify, they must encapsulate ("close over") the lexical scope surrounding their creation - that is, variables defined outside the scope of the function itself but within the scope of its definition are still available whenever the function is called, even if the calling point is after the referenced variable would otherwise have gone out of scope and had its storage recycled.

For example, consider this Javascript:

```js
function makeClosure() {
  var x = "Remember me!";
  return function() {
    return "x='" + x + "'";
  }
}

// console.log(x); 
// The above is an error; x is undefined
var f = makeClosure();
console.log(f());
// The above outputs a string that includes x as it existed when f was created.
```

The variable `x` is defined only within the body of the function `makeClosure`; outside of that definition, it doesn't exist. After we call `makeClosure`, the `x` declared inside it should be gone. And it is, from the point of view of most of the code. But the function returned by `makeClosure` was declared while `x` existed, so it still has access to it when you call it later. That makes it a true closure.

You can have function values that are not closures, because they don't preserve scope. You can also have partial closures; PHP's function values only preserve specific variables that must be listed at the time the value is created.

You can also have callable code values that don't represent whole functions at all. Smalltalk calls these "block closures", while Ruby calls them "procs", though many Rubyists just call them "blocks", because they're the reified version of what's created by the `{`...`}` or `do`...`end` syntax.  What makes them distinct from lambdas (or "function closures") is that they do not introduce a new call level.  **If the code in the body of a block closure invokes `return`, it returns from the outer function/method the block closure exists within, not just the block itself.**

That behavior is critical to preserving what R.D. Tennent labeled the "correspondence principle", which states that you should be able to replace any code with an inline function containing that code in the body and called immediately.  For instance, in Javascript, you can replace this:

```js
x=2
console.log(x)
```

with this:

```js
(function(){x = 2;})();
console.log(x)
```

That example is not very interesting, but the ability to do this sort of transformation without affecting the behavior of the program plays a key role in functional refactoring.  But with lambdas, as soon as you have embedded `return` statements, the principle no longer holds:

```js
function foo1() {
  if (1) {
    return;
  }
  console.log("foo1: This should never run.")
}
foo1()
function foo2() {
  if (1) {
    (function() { return; })();
  }
  console.log("foo2: This should never run.")
}
foo2()
```

The second function is different from the first; the `console.log` is executed, because the `return` only returns from the anonymous function, not from `foo2`. This breaks the correspondence principle.

This is why Ruby has both procs and lambdas, even though the distinction is a perennial source of confusion for newbies.  Both procs and lambdas are objects of class `Proc`, but they behave differently, as indicated above: a `return` just returns from the body of a lambda, but it returns from the method surrounding a proc.

```
def test
  p = proc do return 1 end
  l = lambda do return 1 end
  r = l[]
  puts "Called l, got #{r}, still here."
  r = p[]
  puts "Called p, got #{r}, still here?"
end
```

The above `test` method will never get to the second `puts`, because the invocation of `p` will cause `test` to return immediately (with a return value of 1). If Javascript had block closures, you could do the same thing, but it doesn't (although there is a proposal to add them).

Answer (score 2):

The loud, bearded one has this to say about Closures and Blocks:

http://martinfowler.com/bliki/Closure.html

At one point he says a closure is a block that can be passed as an argument to a method.

Comment: I just find the concept of closure is much more general and well defined than a block. I didn't see the need of blocks if there is already real closures around.

Comment: @WeiQiu As I more or less said in my answer above, the behavior of `return` comprises most of the rationale for block closures as separate entities from function closures.

Answer (score 1):

The terms you are using are most commonly used *together* these days in Ruby, although the constructs previously appeared in Algol, Smalltalk, and Scheme. I would quote the Ruby standard, if there was one.

I'm not sure I'm able to answer your exact question, but I can illustrate. My apologies if you know this already...

```
def f &x
  yield
  x
end

def g
  y = "block"
  t = f { p "I'm a #{y}" }
  y = "closure"
  t
end

t = g
t.call
```

And...

```
$ ruby exam.rb
"I'm a block"
"I'm a closure"
$
```

**So a block is** an anonymous function-like sequence of code attached to a method call. It's used all over the Ruby API. When you make it easy enough to create an anonymous function it turns out they are useful for all kinds of things.

But note that after `f` returns, then `g` returns,  we held on to the block by returning it from `f` (as `x`) and then from `g` (as `t`). Now we call the block a second time. Again, note that `g()` has returned. But the block refers to a local variable in a function instance (and scope) that doesn't exist any more?! And it gets the new value of `y`?!

**So a closure is** a function-like object that is closed over its lexical scope. They are quite challenging to implement because they destroy the do-it-with-a-stack model that is so useful for local variables in function call instances.

---

<sup>1. Ruby has various flavors of closure-like function objects; this is just one of them.</sup>

Comment: The code snippet in this answer is a perfect illustration of why I don't use Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

> 5

That's an *integer*.

> Int workDaysInAWeek = 5

That's an *integer variable* and it may be set to a different *integer*. (If circumstances prevent you from modifying that value, it may be called a *constant*.)

Whereas the above concern numbers, *blocks* and *closures* concern algorithms. The distinction between *blocks* and *closures*, respectively, is also equivalent to the above.